# Append JSON element to JSON array in file using Java

Tags: java, json

Currently I have the following json array object in file(name.json).

```
[{
  "name":"ray",
  "value":"1"
 },
]
```

Now I want to add one more element in this Json array in the file using java. Something like this:

```
[{
  "name":"ray",
  "value":"1"
 },
 {
  "name":"john",
  "value":"2"
 }
]
```

One way could be to read the entire array from the file, append an element to that array and write it back to json file in java. But this is definitely not the optimum way to do this task. Can anyone suggest any other way to this?

Comment: No, the suggested way is the appropriate way.

Comment: deserializing the data, appending data, and then serializing the data is definitely what you should be doing.

Comment: What is wrong with the approach you described? It is the only clean way to do it.

Comment: @nablex problem is when i am adding element frequently to very big JSON array, operation is very slow.(ex -read 10000 elements from the file, add one element to array and then writing back 10001 element back to file)

Comment: then hold the contents in an in memory buffer and only flush it to disk when you absolutely need to.  Or break it into chunks and work with smaller bits.  Also JSON may not be the best storage method if you are working with that much data.  Have you considered a traditional RDBMS

Comment: One alternative would be to make sure that each line in your file is a single JSON string. While reading back from the file, you can build your JSON array.

Comment: json is not really the best format for what you do. what you can do, though, is read from the end until you have passed the `]`, put your object, then write the `]` again

Comment: Can you do this in javascript instead?  Or if they all look like {"name":"foo","value":"bar"}, you can just concat them all together and stick in [, ] parenthesis when you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1 - create a RandomAccessFile object with read/write permissions ("rw");

```
RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile("/path/to/file.json", "rw");
```

2 - set the file cursor to the position of the char "]"

```
long pos = randomAccessFile.length();
while (randomAccessFile.length() > 0) {
    pos--;
    randomAccessFile.seek(pos);
    if (randomAccessFile.readByte() == ']') {
        randomAccessFile.seek(pos);
        break;
    }
}
```

3 - write a comma (if is not the first element), the new json element and the char "]"

```
String jsonElement = "{ ... }";
randomAccessFile.writeBytes("," + jsonElement + "]");
```

4 - close the file

```
randomAccessFile.close();
```